# Android- SearchView in Toolbar

Tags: android, searchview

i want to just add searchview in my app.but i dont want to search any thing just i want the query entered by the user.
so far i tried this code but when i run  my app it crashes.

**Update:**
I tried this one but eventhough my app crashes.

main_menu.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
  android:id="@+id/search"
  android:title="Search"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
  app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SerachView"
  app:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    SearchView searchView=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
         //   Toast.makeText(this,query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this problem please.
ThankYou.

Comment: Time to use a debugger

Comment: Why did you create the SearchView directly instead of adding it as a menu item?

Comment: can you explian how to add via menu item since am new to android.please

Comment: instead of using `SearchView` directly, use it in your `main_menu` in you `menu folder > res`

Answer (score 1):

Lets not use `SearchView` directly, in your `menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and add this simple code to your java :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // Not implemented here
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main_Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search" />
</menu>
```

**onCreateOptionMenu method**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view_menu_item, menu);
    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem);
    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```